# OleDbException when doing INSERT in .mdb database

Tags: c#, t-sql, oledbexception

I have a database which has a table named `Schedule`. It looks like this:

```
Schedule
--------
ScheduleID (number)
BackupID   (number)
Repository (text)
Interval   (text)
Type       (text)
```

Now I am trying to insert values into this table like this:

```
List<string> scheduleData = this.scheduler.getSchedule();
string repository = scheduleData[0];
string interval = scheduleData[1];
string type = scheduleData[2];

List<string> selectedBackup = this.backupForm.getSelectedUser();
string backupID = selectedBackup[0];

string connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\\db\\dbBackupUtility.mdb";
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);
conn.Open();
OleDbCommand sql = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Schedule (BackupID, Repository, Interval, Type) VALUES (@BackupID, @Repository, @Interval, @Type)", conn);
sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BackupID", backupID);
sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Repository", repository);
sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Interval", interval);
sql.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Type", type);

sql.ExecuteNonQuery();

conn.Close();
```

Howevery, I get a OleDbException everytime the program executes this line:

```
sql.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I can't see any other information about the exception but I have tried inserting the values manually using the query analyzer in VS, which strangely works. I have already tried the above with a reader or adapter but I get the same error every time...

Exception Text:

```
Message: "Syntax error in INSERT statement"
StackTrace =    "at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at WindowsFormsApplication1.BackupUtility.scheduler_VisibleChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Teichler\Dropbox\VS_Projects\Projects\WindowsFormsApplication1\WindowsFormsApplication1\MainForm.cs:Line104."
Inner Exception: null
```

Comment: what is exception text?

Comment: I cant find any more infos about the exception, VS just tells me that an OleDbException occured in System.Data.dll. This info is displayed in the output window, program execution goes on normally.

Comment: do one thing, paste above code in try - catch bock. Catch the exception properly and let me know the exception text

Comment: ok I have added further infos. let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Interval` is a [keyword for Jet/Access](http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/what-are-reserved-access-odbc-and-sql-server-keywords.html), change your command into this (surround Interval with brackets):

```
OleDbCommand sql = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Schedule (BackupID, Repository, [Interval], Type) VALUES (@BackupID, @Repository, @Interval, @Type)", conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is comming because you have one value `null` which you are passing as a parameter to insert. Your table column for that value does not accepts `NULL`.

Debugg your code. Identify `NULL` variable and make it in proper datatype.

Use ? instaed @.

Comment: ok I have debugged again but found no null value. all 4 parameters have values in them: backupID has 4, repository has "Daily", interval has "03:00 PM" and type has "Full"

Comment: I also tried it this way, also with the OleDbCommand.AddWithValue method. Sadly, both dont work...

Answer (score 0):

Its maybe because Type is a keyword in sql. Try changing your statement from

```
"INSERT INTO Schedule (BackupID, Repository, Interval, Type)
```

to

```
"INSERT INTO Schedule (BackupID, Repository, Interval, [Type])
```

surrounding Type in brackets